# Python CMD Directory Navigation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, so I'm making a sort of Python middle man. Basically, it takes user input and throws it at Command Prompt, and then returns the output. Here's the code.

```
import os
console=True
while console==True:
    command=input(">")
    os.system(command)
```

The issue is that directory navigation does not seem to be working. The following is what happens when I use the cd command.

```
>cd
C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Stuff
>cd ..
>cd
C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Stuff
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that when you execute the cd command it is executed in another context, it is another independent process because your main process never changes directory. you should use the os.chdir (path) method

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about a way to use Python os. methods and CMD commands in the same interpreter? For example, using an os.chdir(path) method to change directories, and then using a del /f filename to delete a file.

Comment: I thing that You must be verify the command end use custom commands 
You can use a dict to custom commands like cd and exit something like this custom_commands ={
"cd": lambda *args: os.chdir (args [0]), 'exit': exit }

When you read with input you should try verify if is it a custom command or not if it is only call custom_commands[command](arg)

Comment: Cool idea. However, I was thinking a kind of switch would be better. Some way to send your command to the Python-CMD middle man, or to just the Python Command Line.

Answer (score 0):

Changing working directory cannot be done via external commands. You have to parse the command line by yourself:

```
command = input("> ")
cmd = command.split()
if cmd[0] == "cd":
    os.chdir(cmd[1])
```

Of course, the above code is only an example because the use of `str.split()` is too wild. You need to take care of quotes and escaped spaces if you want a fully working "shell".